# Using library defined in global library

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have created a new class library and I've defined it in the global libraries with the name Encryption. I've also added the jar file in this newly created class library. My question is how do I use the this jar file in my other projects now? Do I need to import Encryption in the class I am referencing it from?
This is the print screen of how I'm trying to add jar file in dependency folder and the print screen of the project properties folder:-
[image: Print screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the jar via "add local resources" after creating the dependency, I tried using the option "manually install artifact". This allowed jar file to become available in my dependencies and I could use the class files by using a simple import statement referencing the path to the class files in that jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you make a .jar file for your library classes, you'll have to import it. For netbeans import of libraries below is a screenshot -

[image]

---

### Edit

Why don't you try Add Dependency?

Comment: I added a print screen to my question. I don't have the libraries option in my application. I don't get an option to add library when I right click on project. When I try to add dependency and give the absolute path of the jar file in query, it is unable to find it.

Comment: When I try to add dependency and try to add jar file by using the option of adding local sources, it still shows me that the dependency has not been added.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your netbeans. Why not try re installing it

Answer (score 0):

Once you define it as a global library using netbeans option, you need to do following

- Right click on project -> Libraries
- Go to Project properties
- Compiler Tab
- Add Library Button --> In global Library list you should be able to
  see that library.
- Create a library from your Encryption jar file
- Add this Library to project where you want to use

Then add that global library to your local project, in which you can import the Encryption class and use it.

Comment: I added a print screen to my question. I don't get the option to add library in the compile tab. I don't get an option to add library when I right click on project. When I try to add dependency and give the absolute path of the jar file in query, it is unable to find it.